# In the tenacity documentation is the retry wait exponential incorrectly documented

Tags: python-tenacity, tenacity

In the link https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ the below example states that the wait between retries will be 2*1 (capped at 10 seconds), but should  not this be a linear growth when the multiplier is 1.

```
@retry(wait=wait_exponential(multiplier=1, min=4, max=10))
def wait_exponential_1():
    print("Wait 2^x * 1 second between each retry starting with 4 seconds, then up to 10 seconds, then 10 seconds afterwards")
    raise Exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is `2^x * multiplier` and, in this particular example, the multiplier is 1 (which is a bit confusing for an example). Do not mistake the multiplier with the exponent (`x`): `2^x` is still exponentiation.